# Aggregating CSV Records Using Python

Tags: python, csv, group-by, aggregate

My CSV file looks like this:

```
Mike,6
Mike,5
Bill,3
Bill,1
Sally,4
Sally,2
```

I would like to amend it so the counts are summed by name and looks like this:

```
Mike,11
Bill,4
Sally,6
```

Comment: Robert - Thanks for your thoughts.  I had put some work into it already.  I figured my work could confuse others, though ;)  Below is my solution.  Ideally, each line of results would be a separate dictionary.  If you have an idea for how to do this, please let me know.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Look at the pandas library.

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df_grouped = df.groupby('name').sum()
```

More detail here

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html

Comment: `pandas` is probably overkill for this simple scenario.

Comment: Thanks for the pandas ideas.  I've posted my pandas code below.  I'd like to get each line of results above into separate dictionaries.  If you have ideas on how this can be done, please let me know.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
def records_from_file(fname, column_names):
    with open(fname,'r') as input_handler:
    for line in input_handler:
        line = line.strip('\n') #strip out newline
        x={} #this creates x as an empty dictionary
        for i in range(len(column_names)):
            x[column_names[i]] = line.split(",")[i]  #append each key and value to the dictionary
        yield x

record_stream = records_from_file('names.csv',['name', 'count'])

class Object:                   #Object to store unique data
    def __init__(self, name, count):
        self.name = name
        self.count = count

rownum = 0 #Row Number currently iterating over
list = []  #List to store objects

def checkList(name, count):
    for object in list:  #Iterate through list        
        count=int(count)
        if object.name == name:  #Check if name and produce combination exists
            object.count += int(count) #If it does add to amount variable and break out
            return
    newObject = Object(name, count) #Create a new object with new name, produce, and amount
    list.append(newObject)  #Add to list and break out

for record in record_stream:  #Iterate through all the rows
    name = record['name']  #Store name
    count = int(record['count']) #Store count
    checkList(name, count)

rownum += 1

for each in list: #Print out result
    print each.name,each.count
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('names.csv')
df.columns = ['name','count']
df_grouped = df.groupby('name').sum()
print df_grouped
```